# The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available in SharePoint 2013

Tags: metadata, managed

We have an Internet website implemented with Sharepoint 2013. This website has been working for 10 months normally.

Now, we are having several problems with the Managed Metadata Service for the last 3 weeks. The MMS is not available during some hours each day creating many problems.
We have identified the next problems:
     - It's not possible modify managed navigation
     - It's not possible update SEO properties
     - It's not possible create new publishing pages
     - Multiple errors of navigation on public side of website
     - If the MMS is not available for much time, all publishing pages begin to fail

Event viewer shows the next messages many times each day:

> ```
>  - Id: 8088 Message: "The Managed Metadata Service 'Proxy Managed Metadata' is inaccessible.".
>  - Id: 8313 Message: "A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure ... Affected Endpoint:
> ```
>
> http://xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/MetadataWebService.svc"

When we detect these errors we recycle the Application Pool associated with the MMS and we wait for 20-25 minutes to recover the service. Unfortunately, this procedure don't solve our problems definitively, it's only a temporal solution

We have tried to remove the MMS and create it again using the same database and this test has not been successful

Anybody has any idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Managed metadata services properties and find out the database name (e.g Managed_Metadata_Content)
- Delete the managed metadata service but do not delete the database (e.g Managed_Metagada_Content)
- Create managed metadata services with new database
- Once it managed metadata services created, edit the managed database services properties and rename the database to the old database name (e.g Managed_Metadata_Content) and click Ok. By doing this it will ensure the previous terms set will available
- Delete Managed_Managed_Metadata_Content1 from DB